# Browser does not send cookies when cookie is set on a 303 redirect

Tags: http, cookies

When I set a cookie in a 303 See Other response, the next request (with the redirected-to location) does not contain the specified cookie. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.4 (on 303 response) does not seem to mention cookies specifically. I can reproduce the issue on both current Firefox and current Chrome. As you can see from the Host headers, all of these are made against the same origin.

#### Fails

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:22242
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html
content-length: 694
set-cookie: Authenticating=RrPWNaWsbC013k9QE9zzjJ5C2-c6DKHUnwoKZnL3-knY1aMlxpoGKIm5Kgc
date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 15:13:14 GMT
```

```
POST /mfa/check HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:22242
Cookie: Authenticating=RrPWNaWsbC013k9QE9zzjJ5C2-c6DKHUnwoKZnL3-knY1aMlxpoGKIm5Kgc
```

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
content-length: 0
location: /
set-cookie: Session=k4Bx657138TS2SWdD6KXSxfUy9lddN89HdDOn5_dDLFfvFJwTdEpTGZ_4pw
date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 15:13:53 GMT
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:22242
Cookie: Authenticating=RrPWNaWsbC013k9QE9zzjJ5C2-c6DKHUnwoKZnL3-knY1aMlxpoGKIm5Kgc
```

Why doesn't the latter request send the Session cookie?

#### Works

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:22242
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html
content-length: 718
date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 15:20:41 GMT
```

```
POST /mfa/check HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:22242
```

```
HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
location: /
set-cookie: Session=0WGq8q3Z_chLgf6gUSUnPrivqa8jqvOQJRlDnY8XehQhN4QwIjk0FYwXajI
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 22 Jul 2020 15:21:41 GMT
```

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:22242
Cookie: Session=0WGq8q3Z_chLgf6gUSUnPrivqa8jqvOQJRlDnY8XehQhN4QwIjk0FYwXajI
```

In this seemingly similar case, the cookie is set correctly after the 303 redirect.

Comment: Could this be a server-side issue? I have some memories of webservers stripping headers on redirects. If you're certain the headers arrive then please ignore.

Comment: I'm getting these excerpts from the browser's Developer Tools, so I'm sure they reach the UA.

Comment: Alright, and all the redirects are local redirects to the same domain right? Definitely looks like it in your examples but wanted to make sure this is not a `SameSite` related-issue

Comment: Also ran into this, but not sure if it helps! https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696204

Comment: @Evert thanks for thinking this through with me, found the (silly) problem after all.

Comment: please share! curious

Answer (score 2):

This was a PEBKAC: I figured out that the problem here is the implicit default for the `Path` parameter in `Set-Cookie` headers. The `Path` parameter defaults to the current path, meaning the cookie will not be sent to parent paths.

Because I wasn't focused on the paths that much, it's possible I may have the example requests/responses wrong... I'm going to check what's up with that.

Comment: Yeah, I had the same problem and changing the path to be "/" explicitly, solved it for me.